# replaceAll txt JAVA

Tags: java

Trato Reemplazar subcadenas de un archiivo txt cambiandole la misma palabra pero en mayúscula. El programa abre y muestra el txt, pregunta que subpalabra quiere buscar en el archivo, la almacena en la variable `patron`.
Con ayuda de las clases `pattern` y `matcher` busco la subpalabra dentro del txt y arroja cuantas coincidencias hay. Ahora lo que busco es imprimir el texto pero con las coincidencias que encontro cambiarlas a mayúsculas. Ojala puedan echarme una mano.

```
try {

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src\\cadena.txt")); 

            String texto = "";
            System.out.println("Que palabra desea buscar?");
            String patron = leer.next();

            while((texto = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(patron);
                Matcher match = regex.matcher(texto);
                int count=0;
               while(match.find()){
                  count ++;
                  System.out.println("Encontrado "+match.group() );
               }
               System.out.println("se encontraron "+count+" incidencias");
               System.out.println(texto);
/*  Aca es donde necesito ayuda, stexto quiero asignarle el texto del archivo, y textoNuevo es donde imprimo el texto con las coincidencias buscadas en mayusculas */ 

               String textoNuevo=null;
               while((texto = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
                   String stexto = texto;
                    textoNuevo = stexto.replace(patron, patron.toUpperCase());

               }System.out.println(textoNuevo);
            }
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: y supongo que solo se te imprime la ultima linea no?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿Qué resultado te arroja ese código que has subido?

Comment: Que palabra desea buscar?+"\n"
ca+"\n"
Jack el Destripador (Jack the Ripper en inglés) es el nombre dado a un asesino en serie sin identificar al que se le atribuyen al menos cinco homicidios en Whitechapel, East End de Londres, en 1888, y cuyo modus operandi estuvo caracterizado por cortes en la garganta, mutilaciones en el área genital y abdominal, extirpación de órganos y desfiguración del rostro de mujeres que se dedicaban a la prostitución.
Encontrado ca+"\n"
Encontrado ca+"\n"
Encontrado ca+"\n"
se encontraron 3 incidencias

Comment: Cambia el método de replace por replaceAll y cambia tu patron por una regex, si se te complica eso, entonces itera tantas veces sea necesario tu texto, haciendo contains y luego replace

Answer (score 0):

El método que te propongo es el siguiente:

```
private String replaceAll(String original, CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
    String aux = original;
    while (aux.contains(target)) {
        aux = aux.replace(target, replacement);
    }
    return aux;
}
```